# Quitting a function if all values in an array are true

Tags: c++, arrays, control-flow

There is a simple feature I would like to add to one of the members of a class: I would like to quit the function in case all the values of some boolean (2d) array are `true`.

In the simpler case of a 1d array I can do it this way:

```
int SIZE = 10;
std::vector<bool> myArray(SIZE, true);
int i = 0;
while(myArray[i] and i < SIZE){
    ++i;
    }
if(i == SIZE){
    return;
    }
// rest of the code for array not all true
```

There is probably no quicker way to do it (minus marginal optimizations) but I find it a bit ugly. Are there nicer ways to do it?

=========================================

In the end I decided to implement:

```
{
bool allTrue = true;
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE1 and allTrue; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < SIZE2 and allTrue; ++j)
        allTrue &= myArray[i][j];
if(allTrue)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `std::all_of` from `<algorithm>`:

```
if (std::all_of(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), [](bool b) {return b;})) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: What if it is a `bool **` object ? I picked a `vector` in my example to initialize it in one line, but in my code I used a `bool **`. Can I `std::all(myArray[0][0], myArray[Size1-1][Size2-1])` ?

Comment: With a `bool[N][M]`, you may do something like `std::all_of(&myArray[0][0], &myArray[N][0], [](bool b) {return b;})`. But with `bool**`, you have to call something like : `std::all_of(&myArray[0], &myArray[N], [M](const bool* bs) { return std::all_of(bs, bs + M, [](bool b) {return b;});});`

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions:

```
int my2Da[][2] = {{true, true},{true, true},{true, true}};
int *pa = my2Da[0];
bool flag=true;
for (int i=0;flag && i<(sizeof my2Da)/(sizeof (int));flag &= pa[i++]);
//flag indicates about the result
```

Comment: thank you, I did not know this trick for ''flattening'' an array, could be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

May be and-ing all values? This way:

```
bool r = true;
for (int i=0; i<myArray.size() && r; i++) r &= myArray[i];
return r;
```

Or `std::all_of` if your are familiar with iterators and lambdas.

Comment: Thanks for the input, maybe even `i < myArray.size() and r` in you example  to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

For a 2d vector, you might want to break it down :

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


bool all_true(const std::vector<bool>& v)
{
  return std::all_of(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](const auto& b) { return b; });
}

bool all_true(const std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& vv)
{
  return std::all_of(std::begin(vv), std::end(vv), [](const auto& v) { 
    return all_true(v); 
  });
}

void test()
{
  std::vector< std::vector< bool > > d2 /* = initalise 2d vector */;


  while(!all_true(d2))
  {
    // things you want to do
  }


}
```